# fb-live-stream - Chat is empty after refresh

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I'm trying to integrate the facebook live-stream in our page. It doesn't seem to be all that complicated and it *kinda* works (it posts to the wall and everything) but if I refresh the page with the live-stream in it, it always loads empty ("be the first to comment this").
I can't believe this is normal ...?
The app-id is the same as in the javascript and my meta data.

`<div class="fb-live-stream" data-event-app-id="32343432234" data-width="720" data-height="600" data-via-url="http://bigair.tv/live" data-always-post-to-friends="false"></div>`

Any hints??
thanks,
thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea this is a bug. A fix should be out later today.

Comment: It's back. I guess that was bad timing on my side. Thanks.